# Spring Social Facebook UncategorizedApiException: (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call

Tags: spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social-facebook

I have developed a simple web application that accesses Facebook data through Spring Boot (v1.2.6.RELEASE) and Spring Social Facebook (v2.0.2.RELEASE) similar to the example given [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/)

I have created a new App in Facebook which use Graph API version 2.5.

According to this example i have modified facebookConnect.html putting this different scope to the method POST request:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Extractor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Connect to Facebook</h3>

    <form action="/recommender/connect/facebook" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="public_profile, user_friends, email, user_likes" />
        <div class="formInfo">
            <p>You aren't connected to Facebook yet. Click the button to connect this application with your Facebook account.</p>
        </div>
        <p><button type="submit">Connect to Facebook</button></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

handled by ConnectController which kick off the OAuth authorization code flow...

After OAuth success (with permission granted) and connection is done, i get the following error:

> (#3) application does not have the capability to make this api call.

Here the main part of the controller which handle the redirect from Facebook App:

```
@Controller
```

@Scope(value="session")
public class FacebookExtractor {

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FacebookExtractor.class);

private Facebook facebook;
@Autowired
GraphDatabase graphDatabase;
@Autowired
PersonRepository personRepository;
@Autowired
UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;
@Autowired
AttributeDefinitionRepository attributeDefinitionRepository;
@Autowired
AttributeRepository attributeRepository;
@Autowired
ConceptRepository conceptRepository;
@Autowired
RecommenderGovConsumerRepository recGovRepository;
@Autowired
GovConsumerInfluencedByGovConsumerRelationshipRepository influenceRepository;
@Autowired
ExtractorListener listener;

private String userBind;

@Inject
public FacebookExtractor(Facebook facebook) {
    this.facebook = facebook;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/facebookExtractor")
public ModelAndView FacebookDataUserExtraction() {
    if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/recommender/connect/facebook");
    }
    String account=userBind;
    Long netId = null;
    Transaction tx = graphDatabase.beginTx();
    try {
        User user = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();
        Person p = savePerson(user);
        UserProfile up = saveUserProfile(user);
        up.setUser(p);
        userProfileRepository.save(up);
        p.setProfile(up);
        saveSocialInteractions(up);
        saveSocialPreferences(up);
        personRepository.save(p);
        netId=p.getId();
        tx.success();
    } finally {
        tx.close();
    }
    if (account != null) {
        /*
         * Binding di Facebook riuscito.
         */
        listener.onProfileDataCompleted(netId, SNAccountType.Facebook);
        listener.onInteractionsCompleted(netId, InteractionType.Friendship, SNAccountType.Facebook);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:http://localhost:8080/portal",
                "accountF", account);
    } else {
        //vista opportuna per estrazione avvenuta senza bind
        return new ModelAndView("facebookNoBindExtraction");
    }
}
```

Watching the stack trace error, seems i'm getting error at this line in controller:

> User user = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();

but it is strange because I should have permission to get basic user profile data by default.

**Note: the same code with an older App in Facebook which use Graph API version 2.3 works perfectly, but i need a new one for different purpose and can't force a new App in Facebook to use that version...**

Here the stack error i get....

> 12:01:16.953 [http-nio-9080-exec-5] ERROR
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.social.UncategorizedApiException: (#3) Application
>   does not have the capability to make this API call.] with root cause
>   org.springframework.social.UncategorizedApiException: (#3) Application
>   does not have the capability to make this API call.   at
>   org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleFacebookError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:91)
>   ~[spring-social-facebook-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:59)
>   ~[spring-social-facebook-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:614)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:545)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:253)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:214)
>   ~[spring-social-facebook-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:209)
>   ~[spring-social-facebook-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:53)
>   ~[spring-social-facebook-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:49)
>   ~[spring-social-facebook-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   it.cerict.recommender.extractor.controllers.FacebookExtractor.FacebookDataUserExtraction(FacebookExtractor.java:89)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_60]    at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   it.cerict.recommender.config.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:22)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_60]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_60]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with PROFILE_FILEDS in

```
public User getUserProfile(String facebookId) {
  return graphApi.fetchObject(facebookId, User.class, PROFILE_FIELDS);
}
```

Array PROFILE_FIELDS contains many many fields and as I understang correctly spring-social docs, Facebook returned only this fields you have rights to view.
But now something changed:

```
$curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?access_token=[access_tokens]&fields=[all_the_fields_from_PROFILE_FIELDS]
{"error":{"message":"(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.","type":"OAuthException","code":3,"fbtrace_id":"Antivssjj1d"}}

$ curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token=[access_token]&fields=id,about"
{"id":"1135898619755433"}
```

In the meantime I've found sollution. Instead

```
User profile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile()
```

we can use

```
User profile = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, "id", "name", "link", "email");

//Note: facebook = org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook
//Note: User.class = org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User.class
```

Comment: facebook = org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook and User.class = org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User.class

Answer (score 0):

Or wait the update of spring-social-facebook, there is a pull request pending on the repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook/pull/171

**UPDATE:** Fix for me with the `2.0.3.RELEASE` version.

Comment: I compiled the latest code, But still same exception exists.

Comment: Sadly, they still not merge the pull request, that why it's not working. I don't know when they make a new release. Just wait :(

Answer (score 0):

I continued to get this error, even after adding the `publish_actions` scope that my app needed. The issue in my case was that I needed Facebook to review my app. This is the case if your app was created after April 30th, 2014 and one or more of the following is true:

- You want your App to be listed in the Facebook App Center
- You want to create new, or edit existing, Open Graph actions and stories
- Your app asks people for any extended permissions including publish_actions

Have a look at the [Facebook Login Review FAQs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs#faq_959251624152434) for more info on the review process.